# jquery first option element in select dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

The issue I am having is that for some reason the text "Select A Year" is not the first element to be selected. Instead the text "2003" is the first option element to be selected.

I need to modify it so that "Select A Year" is the first element displayed.

Here's the jQuery code for that.

```
var selectYear = 'Select A Year';
$("#ResidentialStandardYear").append('<option value="' + selectYear + '">' + selectYear + '</option>');
$('option[value="' + selectYear + '"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$.getJSON('/ResidentialBuilding/getYear', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $("#ResidentialStandardYear").append('<option value="' + value.year + '">' + value.year + '</option>');
    });
});
```

Comment: can you just add --- selected -- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the selcted attribute

```
$("#ResidentialStandardYear").append('<option value="' + selectYear + '" selected="selected">' + selectYear + '</option>');
```

Comment: +1 for answering this right as i was typing in selected=selected

Comment: according to this -- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp  -- you dont even need selected="selected"  -- just --- selected

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//$('option[value="' + selectYear + '"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$.getJSON('/ResidentialBuilding/getYear', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $("#ResidentialStandardYear").append('<option value="' + value.year + '">' + value.year + '</option>');
    });
var selectYear = 'Select A Year';
$("#ResidentialStandardYear").prepend('<option value="' + selectYear + '">' + selectYear + '</option>');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/